# "Try Ubuntu without installing" results in graphical artifacts on MacBook

Tags: 12.04, installation, nvidia, macbook, visual-artifacts

I am trying to bless my MacBookPro 5,3 (Unibody/Core2Duo/Nvidia 9400M+Nvidia 9600M GT) with Ubuntu 12.04 (already got rEFIt running), but every time I select *Try Ubuntu without installing*, it will lock up and **always** give me **the same coloured graphical artifacts** all over the screen.

Whether I use a CD-ROM or a USB Stick, it does not change a thing.

[image]

[image]

Is there anything else that can be done or am I stuck for now?

Answer (score 2):

There is two solutions, that i've already tested on my MacBook Pro 5.3:

1. When you see "Try Ubuntu without installing", select it and type `e` for editing and add as kernel option `nomodeset`. You must insert it on the most long line who contains "splash silent", before the "--". After that press <kbd>F10</kbd> key.
2. Alternatively you can download and use [the special iso for Mac here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/precise/daily-live/current/). Then choose "64-bit Mac (AMD64) desktop CD." Everything works well without touching anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have a MacBook pro 5.1 with the same setup of gfx cards.

It messes up because of nouveau/Xorg having  difficulties with your dual card setup.
When you boot in efi mode both cards are enabled.

But there is a way to fix it.

If you disable the card in grub the live cd will boot fine into the graphical environment.
Press 'e' to edit the grub command line.
Add the following on separate lines:

```
outb 0x728 1
outb 0x710 2
outb 0x740 2
oubb 0x750 0
```

This will turn of your 9600 card and switch the display to your 9400 card.

If your display turns totally blank. go into OSX , toggle which card is currently active.
And redo the steps above and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know probably because you are trying to install Ubuntu on a Mac instead of PC? It probably blocked Ubuntu or a display is wrong or your install ISO/CD/USB is corrupt.

Comment: the md5 is correct and i already got it working on two custom build pc's. also there is documentation avaible here on how to install it onto a macbook, so why not? are you from apple? because i would love to put an ubuntu sticker on it. :)

Comment: As @ubuntukeks says, this is a fairly common practice, so there's no reason not to expect it to work.